# .Net Native для Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-native

Возможно ли использование `.Net Native` для обычных приложений `Windows`, или этот компилятор предназначен исключительно для `UWP` приложений?

Если можно, то очень буду рад маленькому мануалу о том как его использовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только для UWP.

Но Вы можете внести свой небольшой вклад в [.Net Native compliler for Desktop](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/9639477--net-native-compliler-for-desktop)